# Cwikel–Lieb–Rosenbljum inequality including zero resonances

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sp.spectral-theory, quantum-mechanics, schrodinger-operators

The Cwikel–Lieb–Rosenbljum inequality asserts that, for any potential $V:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$, we have
$$(\mbox{number of eigenvalue} \leq 0\mbox{ , counted with multiplicity, of }-\Delta+V\,)\leq\\L_n\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}V_{-}(x)^{\frac{n}{2}}dx,$$
for an optimal constant $L_n$ depending only on $n$. To the best of my knowledge, the exact value of $L_n$ is unknown, but there are very sharp bounds.

Now, it seems to me that a similar inequality holds true if in the l.h.s. we count also an eventual zero energy resonance (which roughly speaking is a solution $\psi$ to $(-\Delta+V)\psi=0$, which does not belong to $L^2$ but only to some $L^p$ or to some weighted $L^2$-space, the precise definition depends on the dimension):

$$(\mbox{number of eigenvalue} \leq 0\mbox{ and zero resonances , counted with multipl., of }-\Delta+V\,)\leq \widetilde{L}_n\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}V_{-}(x)^{\frac{n}{2}}dx,$$

for some optimal constant $\widetilde{L}_n$ depending only on $n$.

**Is such inequality actually true? If yes, what bounds can be proved for the constant $\widetilde{L}_n$?**